# Spring-Boot OAuth2 Strange Behavior When Authenticating with Twitch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have been trying to set up OAuth2 with Twitch through Spring for a few days now. I have resolved quite a few problems in that process but this one has stumped me. When I attempt to access one of the endpoints that I am trying to require users to be authenticated with Twitch for I am getting redirected to localhost:8080/login and being shown a page that simply reads "Login with OAuth 2.0" and has nothing else on it. My expectation was that Spring would automatically redirect me to Twitch's authentication portal and then Twitch would send me back to the Spring application after going through the OAuth process. Instead I am simply being shown that page and nothing is happening.

As far as what has been done so far to remedy this problem... pretty much nothing. I have not been able to find anyone else running into this problem so I am thinking that there are a few possible issues... Based on this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ it seems like Spring has out of the box functionality for a lot of different OAuth providers. I am guessing that Twitch is not one of them. That makes me concerned that something on Twitch's backend might be causing this problem for Spring (if that is the case then I will need to make a custom authenticator). The other possibility I have thought of is that Spring might need to be told where to redirect users to for them to get authenticated. If that is the case then I would appreciate some help with that as I have not been able to find any indication that that is something that needs to be done online (and I have no idea how to do it).

Some important files from my project:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.redacted</groupId>
    <artifactId>redacted</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>redacted</name>
    <description>redacted</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.44</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.client-id=redacted
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.client-secret=redacted
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.client-authentication-method=post
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/twitch
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.provider=twitch
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.scope=user:read:email
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.authorization-grant-type=AUTHORIZATION_CODE

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.twitch.authorization-uri=https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.twitch.token-uri=https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.twitch.user-info-uri=https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.twitch.user-name-attribute=redacted
```

and also my SpringSecurityConfiguration file in the event it matters:

```
package com.redacted;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //This allows users to access the "/" and "/Info" endpoints without authenticating with Twitch. To go anywhere else they will have to authenticate.
        httpSecurity.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/Info").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

My project structure:

[image: A picture of my project structure]

Thank you for your time and consideration, I appreciate the help.

-Epoch

Edit:

Something I have recently found that I thought might be prudent to add to this discussion - when I am attempting to access a secured page in my current setup I see this screen: [image]

It looks as if the intended way Spring normally displays this screen is like this: [image]

It's almost as if Spring simply is not seeing my Oauth provider. Not sure if this information is helpful but I thought I would include it. Springs intended behavior for Oauth is that when there is only one provider configured the /login page is skipped altogether. I would actually prefer this behavior to be exhibited (but given it sees no providers I presume it shows the page).

Comment: Take a look at the [property mappings](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-boot-property-mappings) in the reference docs. You may want to specify as many of those properties on the `provider` side as you can. Can you enable trace logging (`logging.level.org.springframework.security=trace`) and provide what is output when you visit a secured page?

Comment: I added as many of those as I could and the problem persists (the only one I am missing is issuer-uri and it looks like Twitch does not provide one of those). I included a pastebin of the stack trace after attempting to access a secured page: https://pastebin.com/yR9eRXKg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to recreate the issue. You have specified:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.authorization-grant-type=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
```

While it should be:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.twitch.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
```

Spring Boot is unable to load your configuration properties properly, so it's as if you have 0 client registrations configured.

Comment: This resolved the issue. There is another resolution to this problem for anyone interested that was recommended to me on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/SpringBoot/comments/r5e0k6/comment/hmnx0yb/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped! Yes, you can also register a bean. Make sure to [read about it in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#oauth2login-register-clientregistrationrepository-bean) as there are quite a few ways to do things depending on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.oauth2Client()` in your `configure` method instead of `.oauth2Login()`.

Comment: Changing it to oauth2Client() caused the server to return a 403 (access forbidden) error. There still does not seem to be a redirect to Twitch's oauth portal.

Comment: Could you verify that the config is loaded by running with `--debug`?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how to verify that the config is loaded based on the debug information. I have an example picture of some of the stuff I was seeing in the [DEBUG] output. It certainly looks like the various oauth2 related dependencies are compiling although I am unsure of whether or not they are configuring based on the debug.

https://imgur.com/TBlUdIn